# How to clear cellcolor for a specific cell in NiceTabular?

Tags: nicematrix, cellcolor

Assume I have a table like this:

```
\begin{NiceTabular}{p{3.8cm}p{3.8cm}}
\CodeBefore
    \rowcolors{2}{white}{gray!30}
\Body
    A & B \\
    C & D \\
\end{NiceTabular}
```

`\rowcolors` gives the row alternating colors. Now I want the cell containing `C` to *not* have a color. I tried:

```
    \cellcolor{} C & D \\
```

but that just gives me

> Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `'

So, how do I clear the color for that specific cell? The page has a background image and thus setting the cellcolor to white isn't a solution.

Comment: Please post a minimal working example which we can compile to produce the same result that you are getting. Your code doesn't produce a table with colored rows. I tried compiling with `xcolor` and `nicematrix` packages. You can't assume all the users know how many packages are needed to produce the result you expect.

Comment: OTOH, can you simply try writing `\multicolumn{1}{p{3.8cm}}{C}` for typesetting the cell containing `C`?

Comment: @Niranjan Sorry, I assumed the [tag:nicematrix] tag was clear enough. I can only guess that you didn't compile multiple times, once won't get the colors correct. And no, `\multicolumn` will still be colored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this example, row #4 was exempt from  the alternate rows colors.

Their cells will have a transparent background.

Then use `\cellcolor` to color the other uncolored cells of the row.

[image: g]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix} 

\pagecolor{yellow} % bg color

\begin{document}        

\begin{NiceTabular}{p{3.8cm}p{3.8cm}p{3.8cm}}
    \CodeBefore
    \rowcolors{1-3,5}{white}{gray!30} % jump over row 4
    \cellcolor{gray!30}{4-1,4-3}% color the other cells of row 4 <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \Body
    A & B &1 \\
    C & D &2\\
    E & F &3\\
    G & H &4\\
    I & J &5\\
    K & L &6 \\
    M & N &7
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Make sure to compile multiple times (two or more times).

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\newcommand{\myred}{\color{red}}%change text color
\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{|*{4}{c|}}%
 [code-before = 
    \rowcolors{1}{red!60}{blue!10}%odd even row colours
    \rowcolor{green}{1} % header colour
    %row-col
    \cellcolor{white}{2-3, 3-4}%cells with white background
    \rectanglecolor{white}{4-1}{5-2} % a rectangle of white cells {top-left}{bottom-right}
    \rowcolor{white}{8}%the rows escaped
 ]\hline
    &   A   &   B   &   C        \\\hline
A   &   1   &   2   &   \myred 3 \\ 
B   &   4   &   5   & 6          \\ 
C   &   7   &   8   &   9        \\ 
D   &   0   &   1   &   2        \\
E   &   3   &   4   &   5        \\
F   &   6   &   7   &   8        \\
G   &   9   &   0   &   1        \\\hline
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This doesn't remove the color, it just makes it white.

Comment: Once you use `rowcolors`/`rowcolor`, the background is drawn on the screen, you cannot undo that. The only way would be to paint it white, as I showed. However, if you are trying to *not* draw specific cells, then you will have to manually colour the cells that needs to be coloured. The cells that you wish to not colour will be manually skipped.

Answer (score 1):

The version 6.26 of `nicematrix` (2023-11-22) provides a special color `nocolor`. The cells marked by this color won’t be colored, whatever the other instructions of coloring which may apply to these cells (in particular, those cells are *not* colored in white).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\pagecolor{gray!10}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{p{3.8cm}p{3.8cm}}[color-inside]
\CodeBefore
    \rowcolors{1}{red!15}{gray!30}
\Body
    A & B \\
    C & D \\
    E & F \\
    \cellcolor{nocolor} G & H \\
    I & J \\
    K & L 
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

As usual with `nicematrix`, you need several compilations.

[image: Output of the above code]